# How to change language in django-modeltranslation in function

Tags: python, django, django-i18n, django-modeltranslation

I am using [`django-modeltranslation`](http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for translation some fields in my models. The package works great, everything is translated.

**But** there is no easy method to switch language manually.

From reading [Accessing Translated and Translation Fields](http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#accessing-translated-and-translation-fields):

> Because the whole point of using the modeltranslation app is translating dynamic content, the fields marked for translation are somehow special when it comes to accessing them. The value returned by a translated field is depending on the current language setting. “Language setting” is referring to the Django `set_language` view and the corresponding `get_lang` function.

Using [`set_language()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#set-language-redirect-view) as it described in documentation doesn't work. Got:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'POST'
```

This is probably happening because i run `set_language()` not in view.

*The question*: How i can switch language for `django-modeltranslation` in basic function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method called [`activate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.activate) from [`django.utils.translation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.translation) which is super simple:

```
>>> from django.utils.translation import activate
>>> activate('en')
>>> Model.objects.first()  # will fetch english version
>>> activate('fr')
>>> Model.objects.first()  # will fetch french version
```

This will work in views as well as plain functions.

If you want to change language just for one fetch and return back to current language you can use [`get_language`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.get_language) from [`django.utils.translation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.translation):

```
>>> from django.utils.translation import get_language, activate
>>> current_language = get_language()
>>> activate('fr')
>>> Model.object.first()
>>> activate(current_language)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe It's too late but you can add middleware in Settings file

> MIDDLEWARE + = [ 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',]

And in request header Key =Accept-Language Value= en,
So now Django will switch the language base on the request header.